# Event source vs original source

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, events

I'm reading C# WPF book and in routed events chapter, event has 2 same properties `Source` and `OriginalSource`. I did not see the difference between them:

**Xaml:**

```
<Button Name="Ok" Click="Ok_Click"/>
```

**Code behind:**

```
private void Ok_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        bool flag = false;
        var source = e.Source;
        var originalSource = e.OriginalSource;
        if (source == originalSource)
        {
            flag = true;
        }
}
```

and `flag` property `true` here, can some one explain why 2 same property or in this case this properties has no effects? or where can we see use case for this properties?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A control can have other controls within it as children. When you subscribe to a event from the control the parent you subscribed to is likely to be the `e.Source` however if the control has children and the child is the one that raised the event then the `OriginalSource` will be the child that raised the event.

A common use case is subscribing to the [`KeyDown`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.keydown(v=vs.110).aspx) event on a `DataGrid`. The source may be the grid but the original source might be the cell (or some component in the cell)