# Determine clicked column in ListView, WPF

Tags: wpf, listview, click

How can I determine, which column was clicked in MouseDown event of ListView (with GridView as its view) in WPF?

Comment: Do you mean click on header or cell?

Comment: Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28688686/2029607).

Comment: @Spawn, I meant cell.

Comment: And by "column" you mean what? What information do you want?

Comment: I edited question. I'm using GridView as view for ListView.